# Installing Torch on Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-ec2, torch, amazon-sagemaker

This took me an excruciatingly long time for me to figure out so I decided to save people the trouble.

Trying to install torch on an ec2 instance with Amazon Linux(redhat) failed with the following command:

```
git clone https://github.com/torch/distro.git ~/torch --recursive
cd ~/torch; bash install-deps;
./install.sh
```

It gave me the error:

```
OpenBLAS Failed to compile
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that you just run the install-deps script and ignore the failure, then run the following line of code:

```
export TORCH_NVCC_FLAGS="-D__CUDA_NO_HALF_OPERATORS__"
```

and follow with the install.sh script as usual:

```
./install.sh
```

[Source Here](https://github.com/torch/torch7/issues/1086)